# Best way to handle multiple click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to complete some action when a link is clicked in my application.

For example, I am creating a manual that has multiple internal links within the document. Currently, I would be handling them like so:

```
function waitForClick()
{
    $('#about').click(function()
    {
        $('#container').slideDown();
    });

    $('#using').click(function()
    {
          changeContent...
    });

    <!-- etc, etc -->            

}
```

Is there a better way to handle multiple click events, so that I don't need an event for every single item. I'm sure there has to be a way to delegate which item was clicked.

HTML:

```
<li><a id="about" href="#">About this Application</a></li>
<li><a id="using" href="#">Using this Manual</a></li>
<li><a id="pages" href="#">Pages:</a></li>

<!-- etc, etc -->
```

This is supposed to be a table of contents for the manual. So there are going to be a lot of local links.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the HTML you've written?

Comment: Why not just use [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) if you're going to have content that changes?

Comment: Its on a mobile device, and I don't want tabs? Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd use something like the below. It avoids a ton of events being cast individually and is scalable enough for your purpose. All you do is add a class of "clickEventClasss" (or whatever takes your fancy) to each element that should have an event an add an id so you can recognise each one.

```
function waitForClick()
{

    $('.clickEventClass').click(function() {

        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        switch(id) {
            case 'about':
            //Logic
            break;
        case 'using':
            //Logic
            break;
        }

    });         

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could bind click events to classes rather than ID's.

```
<a class="navigationLink" href="home.com">Home</a>
<a class="navigationLink" href="about.com">About</a>
<a class="navigationLink" href="contactus.com">Contact Us</a>

$(".navigationLink").click(function() {
    //Do something cool
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class where you assign the click event to.

After this the following is possible:

```
$(".class").click(function()
{
    if($(this).attr("id") == "about")
    {
        //code here
    }
    else if($(this).attr("id") == "using")
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Should store the ID in a variable before you start the conditionals, using $(this) over and over (or any element) is slower than grabbing it once and storing it in a variable as it doesn't need to access the DOM over and over.

Comment: It would be easier to just use `this.id`